# No static IP until a device is connected on Raspberry Pi3 jessie?

Tags: pi-3, networking, raspbian-jessie, static-ip

I am using the jessie version 2017-07-05 on Rpi3. I have set the a static IP address for eth0 interface using dhcpcd.conf as shown below.

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.0.10/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1
```

After doing the changes, I have rebooted the device and ran `ifconfig` But eth0 interface doesn't have any IP. 
Then I connected a laptop to the ethernet port. Again ran `ifconfig` but at this time, eth0 interface shows the IP. So to confirm, I removed the cable from the laptop and ran `ifconfig` once again, and at this time IP address for eth0 is vanished.

So eth0 get the IP address only when a device is connected to the ethernet port. Why this happens?

Because when I used interfaces file( on older raspbian version) for setting the static IP, it's not required to connect a device at eth0 inorder to get the IP address.

I have a problem that dnsmasq is failed to start at boot due to the eth0 interface is not assigned with the static address. So I have to restart the Rpi with a device is connected to it.

Comment: there's no point in an ethernet port having an IP address with nothing connected - so, there is no problem

Comment: But what is the difference when we use interfaces file? It assign IP even if there is no device connected.

Comment: Haven't heard about this problem if using **Raspbian Stretch**. You may consider to upgrade.

Comment: That's not possible. Since we are using jessie in lot of devices.

Comment: Here is asked exactly the same question: [Use of bind-interfaces in dnsmasq?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/95084/79866). Do you also use the option `bind-interfaces` in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`?

Comment: @Ingo Yes. But as he mentioned; Is it a problem to listen on all IP addresses.?

Comment: As per the question you mentioned, Is there a chance to listen dnsmasq on wlan0?

Comment: I don't know. I'm not using **Rasbian Jessie** anymore and I'm not very familiar with `dhcpcd`. I use `systemd-networkd` with which you can exactly control when what service on which interface has to start.