# Use of bind-interfaces in dnsmasq?

Tags: networking, raspbian-jessie, pi-3b+, static-ip

We have used `dnsmasq` to set up a wifi to ethernet router on raspbian jessie. I have configured eth0 for static IP address using dhcpcd.conf file and it is given as follows.

```
interface eth0
static ip_address 192.168.42.1/24
static routers=192.168.42.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.42.1
```

But this assigns IP address only when a device is attached to it. At the time of development, I didn't connect a device.

`dnsmasq.conf` file for the router look like as follows.

```
interface=eth0
listen-address=192.168.42.1

# Bind to the interface to make sure we aren't sending things
# elsewhere

bind-interfaces
server=8.8.8.8 # Forward DNS requests to Google DNS
domain-needed # Don't forward short names

# Never forward addresses in the non-routed address spaces.
bogus-priv
# Assign IP addresses between 192.168.42.2 and 192.168.42.100 with a
# 12 hours lease time

dhcp-range=192.168.42.2,192.168.42.100,12h
```

Then I tried to start dnsmasq and it was a failure. `dnsmasq` failed to start because the eth0 has no IP.

I have connected a device to eth0 port and again tried to start `dnsmasq` and it worked now.

But on each reboot, I need to start the `dnsmasq` manually. After the research on google, I found that commenting the line `bind-interfaces` will help. So I commented the line and `dnsmasq` start to work at boot.

According to the man page, I understand that it is used for multiple interfaces, isn't it?

Actually, I didn't know what `bind-interface` do? How they affect my router? Can you anyone help me with examples to understand the usage of `bind-interface`?

Comment: Remove the `static routers=192.168.42.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.42.1`You state you are setting up "a wifi to ethernet router" have you configured routing and masquerade

Comment: You do not need to specify `bind-interfaces` You should not need `listen-address` either

Comment: @Milliways yes i defined nat rules. Can you explain with reason? Why don't need static_router and domain_name_server? If I didn't provided bind-interface , it will listen on all ip addresses, is that any problem?

Comment: I do not claim to be an expert on routers, but have never needed to set this on an Access Point. It was a suggestion to try. It is the job of the DHCP server to specify these parameters. I suggest you read `man dnsmasq`

Comment: Ok i will try that, But when i use `/etc/network/interfaces` file, there was no problem with dnsmasq.

Comment: @Milliways I have tried that but it still doesn't show IP address until a device is connected.

Comment: If you really are using Jessie (WHY??) which still relies on /etc/network/interfaces you probably need other changes.

Comment: @Milliways Most of our system work on jessie. So I have to work in Jessie. Actually I was using interfaces file to set up static IP but now i decided to use dhcpcd since wifi networks are not showing on GUI when dhcpcd is disabled